# Is there a better way to design this PHP function?

Tags: php

It works but maybe someone of you knows if there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php if ($md_options->mobileversion == true) {;?><!-- Ok Mobile mode is ON -->
    <?php if (detectdevice() != 'true') {;?><!-- Now if we are NOT on a mobile let's start! -->
        <?php if ((is_single()) && ($metaBox == true)) {;?><!-- If is Single and 360Panorama is set let's show panorama -->
            <?php include('360ok.php');?><!-- Houston we have a panorama! -->
        <?php } elseif ((!is_single()) || ($metaBox != true)){;?><!-- Each page that hasn't set a panorama will check... -->
            <?php if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {;?><!-- Do you want to show a slideshow? -->
                <?php include('slideshowhome.php');?><!-- What a nice slideshow! -->
            <?php } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {;?><!-- You prefer a video? let's show it! -->
                <?php include("video/video.php");?>
            <?php };?><!-- Closes video option -->
            <?php if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center'){;?><!-- Let's show the post next to the video or slideshow if it is possible -->
                <?php include('postheader.php');?>
            <?php };?><!-- Closes POSTHEADER -->
        <?php };?><!-- Close Else if !is_single || $metabox != true -->
    <?php };?><!-- Closes the function that checks if we are on a mobile or not -->
<?php } elseif ($md_options->mobileversion != true) {;?><!-- Closes mobile version ON/OFF -->
    <?php if ((is_single()) && ($metaBox == true)) {;?><!-- If is Single and 360Panorama is set let's show panorama -->
        <?php include('360ok.php');?><!-- Houston we have a panorama! -->
    <?php } elseif ((!is_single()) || ($metaBox != true)){;?><!-- Each page that hasn't set a panorama will check... -->
        <?php if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {;?><!-- Do you want to show a slideshow? -->
            <?php include('slideshowhome.php');?><!-- What a nice slideshow! -->
        <?php } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {;?><!-- You prefer a video? let's show it! -->
            <?php include("video/video.php");?>
        <?php };?><!-- Closes video option -->
        <?php if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center'){;?><!-- Let's show the post next to the video or slideshow if it is possible -->
            <?php include('postheader.php');?>
        <?php };?><!-- Closes POSTHEADER -->
    <?php };?><!-- Close Else if !is_single || $metabox != true -->
<?php };?><!-- If mobile mode is OFF this closes the IF -->
```

The same code (without extraneous `<?php ?>` tags):

```
<?php

if ($md_options->mobileversion == true) {
    if (detectdevice() != 'true') {
        if ((is_single()) && ($metaBox == true)) {
            include('360ok.php')
        } elseif ((!is_single()) || ($metaBox != true)) {
            if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
                include('slideshowhome.php');
            } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {
                include("video/video.php");
            }
            if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
                include('postheader.php');
            }
        }
    }
} elseif ($md_options->mobileversion != true) {
    if ((is_single()) && ($metaBox == true)) {
        include('360ok.php');
    } elseif ((!is_single()) || ($metaBox != true)) {
        if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
            include('slideshowhome.php');
        } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {
            include("video/video.php");
        }
        if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
            include('postheader.php');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Is there a faster way to reach the same point?

Comment: Ow! Ow! Ow! Oh the horror.

Comment: Maybe clean up the code first to remove all those extraneous <?php ?>.   This is a bit of a wtf posting atm.  Freudian I know but somehow I managed to read your sig as Maldesign on first glance as a result too :-)

Comment: Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the `?>` close tag implies a `;`. So writing `?>` is similar to writing `; ?>`. Adding another `;` before it would be similar to writing `;; ?>`.

There are many things you can do to improve that.

- Remove the `<?php ... ?>`. Just open a `<?php` tag and close it with `?>` after writing the whole logic.
- Replace the `if (something == true) { ... } else if (something != true) { ... }` logic with `if (something) { ... } else { ... }`
- Remove extraneous parenthesis.
- Extract the logic into the component parts and try to simplify it.
- Stop calling the same function over and over by simply storing its return value.

From what I can gather, the code has the purpose of including one of: "360ok.php", "slideshowhome.php" or "video/video.php" and "postheader.php" in certain situations. You could base the logic around that.

Simplifying the logic to make it more readable:

```
<?php

if ($md_options->mobileversion) {
    if (detectdevice() != 'true') {
        if (is_single() && $metaBox) {
            include('360ok.php');
        } else {
            if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
                include('slideshowhome.php');
            } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {
                include('video/video.php');
            }
            if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
                include('postheader.php');
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    if (is_single() && $metaBox) {
        include('360ok.php');
    } else {
        if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
            include('slideshowhome.php');
        } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {
            include('video/video.php');
        }
        if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
            include('postheader.php');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

From this I understand that there are 2 cases:

- if `$md_options->mobileversion` AND `detectdevice() != 'true'`
- if not `$md_options->mobileversion`.

In each of these cases, the logic is the same, so we can simplify it further:

```
if (!$md_options->mobileversion || detectdevice() != 'true') {
    if (is_single() && $metaBox) {
        include('360ok.php');
    } else {
        if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
            include('slideshowhome.php');
        } elseif ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'false') {
            include('video/video.php');
        }
        if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
            include('postheader.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if the value of `$md_options->slideorvideo` can be either the string `'true'` or `'false'`, then we can simplify it even further:

```
if (!$md_options->mobileversion || detectdevice() != 'true') {
    if (is_single() && $metaBox) {
        include('360ok.php');
    } else {
        if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
            include('slideshowhome.php');
        } else {
            include('video/video.php');
        }
        if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
            include('postheader.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Clear and concise code is often more readable and maintainable than overly verbose code. Also, there's no reason you can't include the comments as PHP comments, but only the relevant ones that hint to why a certain file is included. For example:

```
// only do this if mobile mode is ON and we're not on a mobile,
// or if mobile mode is OFF
if (!$md_options->mobileversion || detectdevice() != 'true') {
    if (is_single() && $metaBox) {
        // if is single and 360 panorama is set, let's show panorama
        include('360ok.php');
    } else {
        // show the slideshow or the video, according to the user's preferences
        if ($md_options->slideorvideo == 'true') {
            include('slideshowhome.php');
        } else {
            include('video/video.php');
        }

        // if possible, let's also show the post next to it
        if ($md_options->slivideoposition != 'center') {
            include('postheader.php');
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's really no need for the extra comments next to the `else` for example, since you can read both the code and the relevant comments fluently. Any extra comment would just be in the way and make the important comments less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Two easy things to improve the code:

- Convert the HTML comments into PHP comments if they belong to the PHP code.
- Switch from doing indentation in HTML for PHP code, to just indent in PHP. This should remove all superfluous `<?php` and `?>` tags as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. As you can see I m something like a 'self (bad) made' programmer and I've a lot to study! Usually prigramming isn't my job, I'm a manager, I have ideas and someone else make it real but I would like to learn and... Your answer helped me a lot! Do you know a good tutorial about how to detect mobile phones using PhP? I am using an open source script but it has a few bugs...